# Understanding servlet filter redirect behavior

Tags: http, servlets, redirect, servlet-filters

I have the following filter code:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/faces/*")
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

    System.out.println("No Filtering");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}
```

Starting project in NetBeans will results in printing "No Filtering" twice, as one time for intercepting request, the second will be for intercepting response.
So far so good but until now there's no filtering. Updating web page or submitting a form with POST method will results in the same way. 
Now adding the following filtering condition:

```
if ( !req.getRequestURI().toLowerCase().endsWith("/index.xhtml")
            &&(session.isNew() || session.getAttribute("username") == null))    {
        System.out.println("directed");
        res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/index.xhtml");
    }else{
    System.out.println("not directed");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);}
```

Will results in printing "directed" once as expected. Now when updating web page or submitting a form here comes the problem, nothing printed even "No Filtering" will not printed? it seems like the filter is not applied to the HTTP request and I can't understand why?
Here's my web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**UPDATE1:**
I tried setting HTTP response status to 302,303,307 but nothing changes.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800688/does-my-filter-run-in-an-infinite-redirect-loop

Comment: Nothing useful on the mentioned link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800688/does-my-filter-run-in-an-infinite-redirect-loop

Comment: Also the question is not structured well, I'm afraid I misunderstood...

Comment: Wait, why do you have the filter configured both in the web.xml and by annotations?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, this is an old version of web.xml used originally without annotation .... the question is updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        String requestPath = req.getRequestURI();
        PrintWriter out =res.getWriter();
        if(session.getAttribute("UserName")==null)// Check for null user
            {
            if(needsAuthentication(requestPath)) //If user is on Login.jsp it lets user to stay there
                {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
                }
            else
                {//If user is not on login page with session attribute null it will check if the form has submitted user name and password
                    if((req.getParameter("username"))==null)
                        {//If no user name and password is submitted it means user is trying to access other pages without login so 
                        //this condition will land user on login page 
                        out.println("Please Login !");
                        RequestDispatcher rd =req.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
                        rd.include(req, res);
                        }
                    else
                            {
                                if ((req.getParameter("username")).equals("admin")&&(req.getParameter("password").equals("123")))
                                    {//If correct credentials are submitted user session is started 
                                        LoginUser user =new LoginUser();
                                        user.setUserName("admin");
                                        session.setAttribute("UserName", user.getUserName());
                                        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
                                        chain.doFilter(req, res);
                                    }
                                else 
                                        {//This will send user to login page again when wrong credentials are set
                                        out.print("Incorrect UserName or Password");
                                        RequestDispatcher rd =req.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
                                        rd.include(req, res);
                                        }
                            }
                }       
            }
        else//This else part is checked when the user session is not null 
            {
            if(session.getAttribute("UserName").equals("admin"))//if user is valid it will continue the flow   
                {
                System.out.println("In Second If");
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
                }
            else        
                { //if user is invalid will land up on login page
        System.out.println("In Second Else");
        req.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }

            }
        }
```

try using this  and her's the method

```
private boolean needsAuthentication(String requestPath) {
         {
               String validNonAuthenticationUrls ="/Login.jsp";

                    if (requestPath.endsWith(validNonAuthenticationUrls)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }   
         }
```